# Will this RAM work with Asus P6X58-E WS

Tags: memory, motherboard

My question is will this ram modules (SK Hynix HMT351U6EFR8C and Hynix HMT351U6CFR8C) work with my Asus P6X58-E WS motherboard?

Answer (score 0):

> My question is will this ram modules (SK Hynix HMT351U6EFR8C and Hynix HMT351U6CFR8C) work with my Asus P6X58-E WS motherboard?

HMT351U6EFR8C and HMT351U6CFR8C are both the same part.  They are both linked to a 4GB PC3-12800 DDR3 1600MHz non-ECC Unbuffered CL11 memory module.

Your motherboard supports all non-ECC DDR3 memory, however there are CPU contraints that might exist, but don’t apply to these specific modules.

> Due to Intel spec definition, DIMMs of DDR3 1800 MHz or above are supported by specific CPU models only

These are the supported DDR frequencies the motherboard supports.

- 1866(O.C.)
- 2000(O.C.)
- 1800(O.C.)
- 1600(O.C.)
- 1333
- 1066

Source: https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/P6X58E_WS/specifications/